# how to plot a structured data file with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data file which has the following structure:

```
cat data.dat
%        1
0.9  0.9  0.6  0.5
0.0  0.1  0.3  0.2 
0.5  0.2  0.0  0.1
%        2
0.2  0.6  0.2  0.3
0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2 
0.4  0.2  0.1  0.1
```

I just showed a simple example with only 2 sets of data but the file
is much more larger than this. What I want is to read the file with 
Python and then tell Python to workout the set which starts with `%     2`
as follows. From this set I would like to plot the row=1 w.r.t. the 
array of integers 1,2,3,4 in this case.

I can do it with GNUPLOT but I spent lot of time because first I need
to cut the set I want and paste it in a temporary file. Second, I use AWK
to transpose the matrix.

I wonder if what I proposed is possible in Python.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to load the file in structured data to use [pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you need a possibility to access various data from file (considering @gboffi [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417873/5510499), there are a restriction that set labels are in consecutive order):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = []

with open('cat_data.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[1].isalpha():
            continue
        if line.startswith('%'):
            data.append([])
            continue
        data[-1].append([float(x) for x in line.split()])

# Now you have all values in data:
# [[[0.9, 0.9, 0.6, 0.5], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2], [0.5, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1]], [[0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3], [0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]]]

_set = 2
row = 1 # Corresponds to 0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2

plt.plot(range(1, 5), data[_set - 1][row])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would read that file in using pandas, find the index of the row that starts your data and scrape off anything above (inclusive), find the index of the next % sign and scrape out everything below (inclusive).  From there you can either plot in pandas, or if you have a specific plotting tool in mind remove the raw data from the pandas df and plot.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
#df = pd.read_csv(myFile.csv,header = None)
df = pd.DataFrame([['cat data.dat',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],['%        1',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], [0.9,  0.9,  0.6,  0.5],[0.0,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2]
                   ,[0.5,  0.2,  0.0 , 0.1],['%        2',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                  [0.2,  0.6,  0.2,  0.3],[0.2,  0.1,  0.1,  0.2 ],[0.4,  0.2,  0.1,  0.1]])

#filter above
start_index = df[df[0] == '%        2'].index.tolist()[0]
df = df[df.index > start_index]

#filter below
#end_index = df[df[0] == '%        3'].index.tolist()[0]
#df = df[df.index < end_index]

#plot
df.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("datafile") as f:
    r=filter(None,f.read().split("%"))[1]
dat=r.split("\n")
dat.pop(0)
data=[map(float,filter(None,i.split(" "))) for i in dat][0]
```

there is your 1st row data now plot it with the your array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

If your block labels are only consecutive integers, other solutions will work OK (I'm especially thinking of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417160/2749397)); otoh if the labels are not consecutive and possibly also non-numerical, a better solution would be a dictionary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {}
f = open('file.dat')
for line in f:
    elts = line.strip().split()
    if elts[0] == '%':
        k = elts[1]
        d[k] = []
    else:
        d[k].append([float(elt) for elt in elts])

plt.plot(range(1, 5), d['2'][1])
plt.show()
```